# Return type of slice for a user-made container in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I am creating a custom container that returns an instance of itself when sliced:

```
from typing import Union, List

class CustomContainer:
    def __init__(self, values: List[int]):
        self.values = values

    def __getitem__(self, item: Union[int, slice]) -> Union[int, CustomContainer]:
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            return CustomContainer(self.values[item])
        return self.values[item]
```

This works but comes with the following problem:

```
a = CustomContainer([1, 2])
b = a[0]  # is always int, but recognized as both int and CustomContainer
c = a[:]  # is always CustomContainer, but recognized as both int and CustomContainer

# Non-scalable solution: Forced type hint
d: int = a[0]
e: CustomContainer = a[:]
```

If I change the return type of `__getitem__` to only `int` (my original approach), then `a[0]` correctly shows type `int`, but `a[:]` is considered a `list` instead of a `CustomContainer`.
As far as I understand, there used to be a function in python2 to define how slices are created, but it was removed in python3.

Is there a way to give the proper type hint without having to force the type hint every time I use my container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload), which allows you to register multiple different signatures of a function with a type checker. Functions decorated with `@overload` are ignored at runtime, so you'll typically just fill the body with a literal ellipsis `...`, `pass`, or a docstring. This also means that you have to keep at least one version of the function that isn't decorated with `@overload`, which will be the actual function used at runtime.

If you take a look at `typeshed`, the repository of stub files used by most major type-checkers for checking the standard library, you'll see this is the technique they use for annotating `__getitem__` methods in custom containers such as [`collections.UserList`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/b9e1d7d522fe90b98e07d43a764bbe60216bc2c4/stdlib/collections/__init__.pyi#L66). In your case, you'd annotate your method like this:

```
from typing import overload, Union, List

class CustomContainer:
    def __init__(self, values: List[int]):
        self.values = values
        
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, item: int) -> int:
        """Signature when the function is passed an int"""
        
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, item: slice) -> CustomContainer:
        """Signature when the function is passed a slice"""

    def __getitem__(self, item: Union[int, slice]) -> Union[int, CustomContainer]:
        """Actual runtime implementation"""

        if isinstance(item, slice):
            return CustomContainer(self.values[item])
        return self.values[item]

a = CustomContainer([1, 2])
b = a[0]
c = a[:]

reveal_type(b)
reveal_type(c)
```

Run it [through MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=f989e4b35555512f2cec03ae466f391e), and it tells us:

```
main.py:24: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
main.py:25: note: Revealed type is "__main__.CustomContainer"
```

**Further reading**

The mypy docs for `@overload` can be found [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html).

Comment: thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Aba no worries, glad I could help!